# Possible to run commands after npm start on the same console?

Tags: reactjs, npm, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to run Google Lighthouse on a pipeline in my bitbucket repository. In the pipeline, the scripts that I'm running are:

```
- npm install
- npm run
- <<Google Lighthouse scripts>>
```

However, the pipeline stops after `npm run` is executed. Is it possible to run commands after `npm run`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally in unix-systems (must been also windows but not sure how) you can run a process in background with:

```
command &
```

So in your case

```
npm run &
```

The downside is, you can't kill the process by cntrl-c. You need the process-id (PID) to kill the process. Lets asume the PID is 12345 then you need to do

```
kill 12345
```